# How to get the minimum of the last 1000 days in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to get the minimum of the last 1000 days in Pinescript. It can't be done with the ta.min method, as there is no parameter for length. Any ideas on how to do it alternatively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ta.min()` is specifically for all-time lows. You can try using `ta.lowest(low, 1000)` instead.